# How can we define the error of the CORDIC Algorithm for calculating sin(x) as a function of the number of iterations/rotations performed?

Tags: computer-science

I intend on comparing the CORDIC algorithm and the Taylor Series expansion for computing sin(x). However, I need to compare them on the basis of accuracy and time complexity.

How can we determine the error of the CORDIC Algorithm (similar to how the Lagrange Remainder can be applied to the Taylor Series for an nth degree polynomial)?

Thanks!

Comment: In most practical cases, target precision and input range are known in advance, which means that Taylor is not optimal (there are polynomials of same degree with smaller (absolute or relative) error on the target interval).